# Boschloo or Barnard? In which case?

Tags: chi-squared-test, statistical-power, contingency-tables, fishers-exact-test

For 2x2 contingency tables, my understanding is that Boschloo and Barnard both have uniformly more power than Fisher's exact test (even if all marginals are fixed??). But I am still confused about the difference between these tests.

In the end which one should be used in which case?

[This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/174628/140570) answer indicates that Boschloo might be better but slower. But I cannot find any reference in the literature.

We are adding Barnard ([done](https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/reference/generated/scipy.stats.barnard_exact.html)) and Boschloo ([here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/13951)) in SciPy and we are unsure about how to document the difference and give *practical* recommandations on these methods.

Comment: Maybe this paper helps, though it recommends tests other than Boschloo's or Barnard's: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1440-1681.12052